# EnumDropdownListFor includes the enum name as an option

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, enums

I have the following enum:

```
public enum EventType : int
{
    [Display(Description = "Downtime")]
    Downtime = 0,
    [Display(Description = "Speed")]
    Speed = 1,
    [Display(Description = "Quality")]
    Quality = 2
}
```

I am creating a dropdown list for it using:

```
@Html.EnumDropDownListFor(m => m.Type, "Event Type", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

The options I get in the dropdown are:

1. Event Type
2. Downtime
3. Speed
4. Quality

Why *on earth* is `Event Type` an option? And what possible value could it represent??

The `[Display]` attributes are my feeble attempt at fixing this...

Any ideas?

Comment: You added it with the 2nd parameter of the method. Its the 'label' option with a `null` value (used to validate that a selection is made)

Comment: @StephenMuecke That's it.. Thanks!

Comment: See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.selectextensions.enumdropdownlistfor(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.SelectExtensions.EnumDropDownListFor%60%602%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper{%60%600},System.Linq.Expressions.Expression{System.Func{%60%600,%60%601}},System.String,System.Object%29) for reference. I believe you're using given overload.

Answer (score 1):

At first you need to create a HTML Helper extension like:

```
 public static class HtmlHelperExtensions
{       
    private static string GetDisplayName(this Enum enumeration)
    {
        var enumType = enumeration.GetType();
        var enumName = Enum.GetName(enumType, enumeration);
        var member = enumType.GetMember(enumName)[0];

            var attributes = member.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayAttribute), false);
            var attribute = (DisplayAttribute)attributes[0];
            var displayName = attribute.Name;

            if (attribute.ResourceType != null)
            {
                displayName = attribute.GetName();
            }

        return displayName;
    }


    public static MvcHtmlString EnumDropDownFor<TModel, TEnum>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TEnum>> expression, Func<TEnum, bool> predicate=null, string optionLabel=null, object htmlAttributes=null) where TEnum : struct, IConvertible
    {
        var enumList = predicate == null ? Enum.GetValues(typeof(TEnum))
            .Cast<TEnum>()
            : Enum.GetValues(typeof(TEnum))
                .Cast<TEnum>()
                .Where(e => predicate(e));

        var selectList = enumList
            .Select(e => new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = Convert.ToUInt64(e).ToString(),
                Text = ((Enum)(object)e).GetDisplayName(),
            }).ToList();
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(optionLabel))
        {
            selectList.Insert(0, new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = optionLabel
            });
        }

        return htmlAttributes==null 
            ? htmlHelper.DropDownListFor(expression, selectList) 
            : htmlHelper.DropDownListFor(expression, selectList, htmlAttributes);
    }
}
```

Then if your `Enum` like bellow

```
public enum EventType
{
    [Display(Description = "Downtime")]
    Downtime = 0,
    [Display(Description = "Speed")]
    Speed = 1,
    [Display(Description = "Quality")]
    Quality = 2
    [Display(Description = "Test")]
    Test = 3
}
```

and you are don't want to load `Test` then use:

```
@Html.EnumDropDownFor(model => model.Type, types => types != EventType.Test, "Event Type", new {@class = "form-control"})
```

Or if you need to load all then:

```
@Html.EnumDropDownFor(model => model.Type, optionLabel:"Event Type", htmlAttributes:new {@class = "form-control"})
```